# Most likely number of matching cards when two people select different numbers of cards from their own packs

Tags: probability, combinations

Two people R and T each have a standard deck of playing cards and each randomly chooses  as many cards as they like  from their packs. We know that each pack has N=52  different cards and that (say) R chose 10 cards and T 30 but we do not know what specific cards they chose.

How do we now calculate the probability (p(M))  of  8 of the cards chosen by R and T being the same (e.g. both chose 6 of clubs, etc.)? or of 5 cards being the same? What we really want to know is the most likely number of chance matches in this scenario.  What is M with the greatest p(M)?

Btw we are not interested in the order of picking cards here: R and T need not draw the same card at the same time in order of picking as each other for it to be a match. Hence I take it that this is a problem of combinations and since there is no replacement, hypergeometric?

Indeed some of the required probabilities seem to be obtainable with the well known formula below, calculating combinations C where one can select different values of M to get p(M) for each value. This works  where R=T, i.e. both people pick the same number of cards, like in lottery analogies where the lottery chooses 6 numbers and people also pick 6 numbers (usually called K in these formulae):
(KCM x ((N-K)C(K-M))) / NCK

But what I need is a formula that also works where K is not the same for the two people. If you like, in the lottery version, it is where the player would be able to choose more numbers than the lottery's six. Looking at formulae I have found involving extra bonus balls or people buying more than one ticket, they don't seem to quite fit my case. Picking 12 numbers and looking for matches with the 6 winning numbers is not the same as buying two lottery tickets of 6, each of which has to be separately judged for matches with the winning numbers in order to win?

I have worked out answers on a very small scale, imagining packs of cards with only  4 cards in them, by constructing tables of all the possible combinations that could occur and counting matches. In the real situation I am interested in packs of 'cards' which could each have 1000 cards in them, however, so I  need a formula. E.g. for N=4, I get by hand that p(M=2) =.75  if R=T=3, and the same from the formula above. Where N=4, R=3, T=2 by hand I get p(M=2) = .5 but I can't find a formula to do this. but I am sure it is out there.

Comment: The distribution may be tough to get at, interesting problem. What is easy is the *expected number* of matches. This should (?) be not far from the most likely number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $^nC_k$, which you are aware of, I shall use $\dbinom{n}{k}$ prevalent here, easier on the eye.

The total combos with $R$ and $T$ choosing $10$ and $30$ is $\dbinom{52}{10}\dbinom{52}{30}$= $D$, say

Suppose 8 cards are the same, this can be in $\dbinom{52}{8}\dbinom{8}{8}=\dbinom{52}{8}$ combos = $A$ (say)

$R$ has to choose 2 more, and $T$, 22 more, from *different* cards, hence $\dbinom{44}{2}\dbinom{42}{22} = B$ (say)

The probability you seek is $\dfrac{AB}{D}$

You can compute like this for any other numbers similarly.
Suppose $R$ chooses $a$ cards, $T$ chooses $b$ cards, and you want $k$ cards common,

$Pr = {\dbinom{52}{k}\dbinom{52-k}{a-k}\dbinom{52-a}{b-k}\over \dbinom{52}{a}\dbinom{52}{b}}$